# django 1.2 GAE python -> converts html to html safe string? replacing <br /> with the string

Tags: python, html, django, google-app-engine

When I render my template in django 1.2 and display strings with a

```
<br />
```

tag I get

```
&lt;br /&gt;
```

instead?

Meaning I actually see the text

```
<br />
```

instead of getting the much desired line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you output the string from a variable using the `{{ string }}` notation. 
If you know the string you are outputting is safe, use the `|safe` filter.

`{{ string|safe }}`

I would have to advise against doing this with any data that was supplied by the user without proper inspection.

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

Comment: Shalom ma nishma :) Thanks! Nah, in this case the text is from the copywriter, we keep it separately from the template to prevent evil from happening when we change the ads wording.

Comment: Cool, this is the exact case then :)